# how to use applescript to move files to new folder by extension, keeping subfolder name

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

Here's what I'm trying to do.

I've got a file structure that contains photos in both JPG and RAW formats. It's a folder called "Photos" with subfolders by date. I'd like to copy just the RAW photos to a new folder, "Photos RAW", but keep the structure by date taken/created.

I can copy just the files using automator or applescript a directory to a new one, but how do I walk the directory tree using applescript so I cover all the subfolders?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You'll see I used "entire contents" to get the files in the subfolders too.

```
set extensionToFind to "raw"

set topLevelFolder to (choose folder) as text
set pathCount to count of topLevelFolder

tell application "Finder"
    -- get the files
    set rawFiles to files of entire contents of folder topLevelFolder whose name extension is extensionToFind
    if rawFiles is {} then return

    -- setup the folder where the files will be moved
    set rawFolder to ((container of folder topLevelFolder) as text) & "Photos_Raw:"
    do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of POSIX path of rawFolder

    repeat with aFile in rawFiles
        set aFileContainer to (container of aFile) as text
        if topLevelFolder is equal to aFileContainer then
            -- here the file is at the top level folder
            set newPath to rawFolder
        else
            -- here we calculate the new path and make sure the folder structure is in place
            set thisFile to aFile as text
            set subFolderPath to text (pathCount + 1) thru -((count of (get name of aFile)) + 1) of thisFile
            set newPath to rawFolder & subFolderPath
            do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of POSIX path of newPath
        end if

        move aFile to folder newPath
    end repeat
end tell
```